# Confusion on Activity Lifecycle

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have one app which authenticate user to access internal activity, App is having several activity which gets data from previous activity

So I am bit confused on activity life cycle

I read Bundle data into local variable in activity OnCreate and reading DB in async task based on that data. this DB data is displayed on my app.

Now if I switch to another app,  will my app have that local variable/Static variable data (read from DB data) with them,

I have SingleInstance class which keeps user ticket etc informations, Is that variable keeps in memory of app if we got phone call in between.

I am bit confused on this part.

As document suggest that you need to store unsaved data in shared preferences.

It would be good if someone highlight on that..

Comment: The data of the activity remains with the activity variables if its loaded even in background... onResume allows you to put some control statements in your code to detect from background to forground

Comment: so if I execute Async task in onCreate and Async task "onPost method" will push already read db data to my UI. This UI will persist data in case sleep or lock unlock or switch to another app

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you need to make sure you understand the difference between a new app and a new activity according to the sentence:

> Now if I switch to another app, will my app have that DB data with them after switching back to my app

If you actually mean different apps, the answer is "NO in another app(in case is your app too)" you cannot have access to another application DB (at least not directly), the only way is if that application implemented a content provider to share its data with another application, by default android applications are like sandbox and do not share any information with other apps unless specifically declared, there's another rules between two apps signed with same key but that's a different story and a huge advance topic not related to this question...

In case that you " mean go to another app (not mine) and then try to use it from MY app again " the answer is "YES", the information in the database is accessible among all the building components like "activity, service" that belong to the same application, information in database is persisted even after closing completely the app (and so is shared preference), but there's a huge different between shared preference and DB, and knowing when to use one or another differentiates between good and excellent developers, golden rule (but not the only or the best) is that, DB is used for complex queries and relational data that needs some sort of preprocessing or postprocessing to get the proper values, mean while shared preference is just a "key/value" map that persist in the application context

Hope this Helps.

Regards!

Comment: I mean DB data mean local variable Data read from DB. so if I execute Async task in onCreate and Async task "onPost method" will push already read db data to my UI. This UI will persist data in case sleep or lock unlock or switch to another app